# OpenGL es 2.0 drawarrays with Triangle_strip

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

According to a lot of examples and tutorials, you can draw a cube in Opengles 2.0 by specifying vertices in space (8 of them if they share the same color, 24 if not).

Then you declare indices in CCW order to fill the vertices with a face.

But then I've seen this instruction

```
gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                            mIndexBuffer);
```

Which in my case draws the cube but some vertices are wrongly connected.

Believing the order of vertices or index were wrong, I've tried a lot of different combinations, leading all to a wrong solid.

Then I've changed this

```
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, ordine.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, ordMem);
```

Which basically says **strips** in place of **triangles** and it worked. So, am I missing somethig important? Or OpenGles 2.0 draw in a different way? Or what?

Comment: If you are drawing your triangles in strip-order, then that means that each odd triangle is wound in reverse. This could explain why some of the triangles are being culled. Without facet culling enabled or anything else that behaves differently depending on which side is being shaded, it really does not matter how you wind your vertices.

Answer (score 0):

I've inverted Matrix.frustum arguments puttin 1 -1 as min max. Inverting them -1 min and 1 max, did the trick.